# Calculating residue $\int_C \frac{8-z}{z(4-z)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to calculate the following:

$$\int_C \frac{8-z}{z(4-z)}dz$$

$C$ is a circle of radius $7$, centered at the origin,negative oriented.

I want to do this via finding the residues at $z=0,4$.

I thought I was meant to use Cauchy integral formula and sum the values, like this:

$$\int_C \frac{f_1(z)}{z} dz = \frac{8-0}{4-0}=2$$
$$\int_C \frac{f_2}{(4-z)}dz = \frac{8-4}{4}=1$$

Then since it is negatively oriented we get, $-2\pi i \times (2+1)=-6\pi i$

But the answer is $-2\pi i$, what have I done wrong?

Comment: you should have $0-4=-4$

Comment: By "negatively oriented", do you mean clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Comment: @robjohn Clockwise, my class says it is positively(oriented) transversed if the bounded region is always to the left

Answer (score 1):

When the denominator is $4-z$, you need to change it to $z-4$ first. This gives you a negative sign. Also, the $2\pi i$ should be included in the answer of the integral.

$$\int_C \frac{f_1(z)}{z} dz = -2\pi i \left(\frac{8-0}{4-0}\right)=-4\pi i\\
\int_C \frac{f_2}{(4-z)}dz =-\int_C \frac{f_2}{(z-4)}dz=2\pi i \left( \frac{8-4}{4}\right)=2\pi i$$

Comment: The answer should be $-2\pi i$, but you are right, I did switch it around woops

Comment: Ahh woops flipped around was correct, let me edit

Comment: @ResidualEnergy: Do you mean the original problem should be $4-z$? That seems more consistent with the answer.

Comment: @ResidualEnergy: I edited too.

Comment: Oh I see, yes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\frac{8-z}{z(4-z)}=\underbrace{\frac2z}_{\text{residue 2}}-\underbrace{\frac1{z-4}}_{\text{residue $1$}}
$$
The integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues times the winding number around each singularity. The total of the residues is $1$ and the winding number is $-1$ (the contour is clockwise). Thus,
$$
\int_C\frac{8-z}{z(4-z)}\,\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\cdot1\cdot-1=-2\pi i
$$

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition puts the residue in the numerator?(or coincidence, and otherwise, how do you read the residue off)

Comment: Indeed, the residue of $\frac{a}{z-b}$ is $a$.

Comment: Well that sure is handy!